# How to retrieve an element ancestor, reckoning from root element?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have an XML document structured that way:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<MPM>
  <MPMEntry>
    <title>Title 1</title>
    <MPMEntry>
      <!-- Nest any number of MPMEntry ... -->
      <title>Title 1.1</title>
      <MPMEntry>
        <!-- Nest any number of MPMEntry ... -->
        <title>Title 1.1.1</title>
        <MPMEntry>
           <title>Title 1.1.1.1</title>
           <DM id="dm_1111a">
             <title>DM title a</title>
             <para>and so on</para>
           </DM>
           <DM id="dm_1111b">
             <title>DM title b</title>
             <para>and so on</para>
           </DM>
        </MPMEntry>
      </MPMEntry>
    </MPMEntry>
    <MPMEntry>
       <title>Title 1.2</title>
      <MPMEntry>
         <title>Title 1.2.1</title>
        <MPMEntry>
           <title>Title 1.2.1.1</title>
           <DM id="dm_1211">
             <title>DM title m</title>
             <para>and so on</para>
           </DM>
        </MPMEntry>
      </MPMEntry>
    </MPMEntry>
  </MPMEntry>
  <MPMEntry>
     <title>Title 3</title>
  </MPMEntry>
  <!-- ... and so on ... -->
</MPM>
```

The `<MPMEntry>`s can be imbricated as many times as required, depending on the writer's will.

When I am processing a given DM element (which is the end-level of the XML structure), I need to be able to retrieve the first-levelled and the second-levelled `<MPMEntry>` (from the root of the XML document) titles it is nested in.

Namely, for `<DM id="dm_1111a">`, I will need to retrieve *Title 1* and *Title 1.1*. For `<DM id="dm_1111a">`, I will need to retrieve *Title 1* and *Title 1.2*.

For the moment, I am using the following XPath (1.0) expressions, which work:

- for the first `<MPMEntry>`: `ancestor::MPMEntry[parent::MPM]/title`
- for the second `<MPMEntry>`: `ancestor::MPMEntry[parent::MPMEntry/parent::MPM]/title`

Here is a simple XSL stylesheet to play with (see it working on http://xsltransform.net/gWvjQf9):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />


    <xsl:template match="MPM">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::DM" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="DM">
        <Level1Title>
            <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::MPMEntry[parent::MPM]/title" />
        </Level1Title>
        <Level2Title>
            <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::MPMEntry[parent::MPMEntry/parent::MPM]/title" />
        </Level2Title>

        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My questions are: is there a simpler or more direct way to retrieve the desired information? Is there a more generic possibility to do this (I very probably will need to get the third level, and so on) - if possible with a numerical index, telling get me the nth-levelled `<MPMEntry>`, from the root element?

Please also note that I need to use XPath 1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use positional predicates on the ancestor axis, keeping in mind that it is a reverse axis:

```
<Level1Title>
    <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::MPMEntry[last()]/title" />
</Level1Title>
<Level2Title>
    <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::MPMEntry[last() - 1]/title" />
</Level2Title>
```